# How to Solve Network Error When Trying to Connect to React App's Proxy Server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, https, firebase-hosting

I'm having trouble connecting to my proxy server on my deployed React app (it was working fine in development).

Essentially, the app lets users add ingredients and get their nutrition data. I have a proxy server to conceal the API key I use to access the API that fetches the nutrition data.

Since deploying, I get the following error message when I try to add ingredients:

[Network Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZCMB.png)

Here is the function in the front-end that makes the request to the proxy server:

```
  const fetchNutritionData = (ingredientName) => {
    const axios = require('axios');
    
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://nutrition-calculator.web.app:8000/fetch',
      params: { query: ingredientName },
    };
    
    return axios
    .request(options)
    .then((response) => {
      response.data.items[0];
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        setIsAPIConnectionDown(true);
      });
  };
```

And here is the code for my proxy server:

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config();

const PORT = 8000;

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.get('/fetch', (req, res) => {
  const ingredientName = req.query.query;

  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://calorieninjas.p.rapidapi.com/v1/nutrition',
    params: { query: ingredientName },
    headers: {
      'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'calorieninjas.p.rapidapi.com',
      'X-RapidAPI-Key': process.env.REACT_APP_RAPID_API_KEY,
    },
  };

  return axios
    .request(options)
    .then((response) => {
      res.json(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
});

app.listen(PORT);
```

I changed fetchNutritionData's options.url from http://localhost:8000/fetch to my actual domain when I deployed. I thought that should work, from what I've read. So, not sure what the issue is. I'm using Firebase Hosting, if that makes any difference.

Can you see where I'm going wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Running a server on port 8000 on your own computer works fine, but online I don't think you can just pick any port. It's not necessary to use a 2nd server anyway, you can use a single express server to 1. serve the React app as static content and 2. serve the API. Just put your built React app in a `public` folder and add `app.use(express.static('public'))`.

Comment: @ChrisG I also tried 443 as the port since I heard that was the standard for HTTPS, but I didn't have any luck with that either. It would return the HTML head as the data and cause a type error. Also, for your suggestion, should fetchNutritionData's options.url just be "https://nutrition-calculator/fetch" then?

Comment: You can use the relative version: `fetch("/fetch")`

Comment: Firebase hosting doesn't run node app. You'll have to add a firebase function. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started